# How to get swfupload to work with Asp.Net MVC 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, swfupload

I'm trying to use the swfUpload jquery/flash plugin for uploads, and I'm following the approach by Steven Sanderson (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/ ). But I can't get it to work. It works fine in the sample application I downloaded from his site. Just to try to get it to work I have tried to copy his page and everything directly in my application, but it still doesn't work.

Here's the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>

    <title>File upload</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/Site.css" />
<%--        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>--%>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/swfupload.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-asyncUpload-0.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="MainContents">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <h1>Your profile</h1>
                <p>(In a real app, other form controls would appear here)</p>
                <p>
                    Upload your photo: <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" />
                </p>

                <input type="submit" value="Save my profile" />
            </form>
        </div>        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#photo").makeAsyncUploader({
                    upload_url: "/Customers/AsyncUpload/",
                    flash_url: '../../Scripts/swfupload.swf',
                    button_image_url: '/Content/blankButton.png',
                    disableDuringUpload: 'INPUT[type="submit"]'
                });
            });        
        </script>  
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the action method:

```
    public Guid AsyncUpload()
    {

        return _fileStore.SaveUploadedFile(Request.Files[0]);
    }
```

This is in a CustomersController controller, and I have this at the beginning of the controller:

```
private IFileStore _fileStore = new DiskFileStore();
```

Just as he does in his sample. Of course I also have the IFileStore interface and DiskFileStore class in place.

I have all the references to the js files and css in the head tag:

```
<head>

<title>File upload</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/Site.css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/swfupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-asyncUpload-0.1.js"></script>
</head>
```

(Although I have used the latest jQuery I have, rather than 1.2.6 which he had in his sample). I know at least that the scripts are triggered, because in FireBug I can see that the input is dynamically changed to a flash object, as it's supposed to be.

The thing is, AsyncUpload() is never even called. I set a breakpoint there which is never reached. And I'm getting different errors. The first time I tried it I got a 302 error in an alert box from the script. (At that time I had other jQuery scripts on the same page, so I started over with a cleaner page using just these scripts). But now I'm not getting any error, I can choose image and all, but then it just stops at the stage where the text says "Uploading...", but I don't see the progress bar or anything, and it never finishes.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did swfupload work with mvc for you ?

Answer (score 1):

use below CSS for fixing Firefox issue

```
DIV.ProgressBar { 
    width: 100px; padding: 0; border: 1px solid black; margin-right: 1em;
    height:.75em; margin-left:1em; display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; 
}
DIV.ProgressBar DIV { 
    background-color: Green; font-size: 1pt; height:100%; float:left; 
}
SPAN.asyncUploader OBJECT { 
    position: relative; top: 5px; left: 10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was it didn't work in Firefox, only IE (for a change...). Something with cookies. For anyone that's interested, see the comments section in Steven Sanderson's blog that I referred to above!